# Chromium --disable-cookie-encryption not working

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I'm staring Chromium (version: 83) in Selenium. I'm starting it with `--disable-cookie-encryption.

```
options.AddArgument("disable-cookie-encryption");
```

On [Chromium website](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags), they refer to [this list](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) of valid arguments.

There is one argument:

> `--disable-cookie-encryption` - Whether cookies stored as part of user
> profile are encrypted.

Once I open the `chrome://version` I can verify that the chrome was started with `--disable-cookie-encryption` argument.

The problem is that once I open the SQLite file where the cookies are stored (on the Default/Cookies file of the profile) they are still encrypted.

I have tried with Google Chrome and with Edge and none of them was working.

Any ideas on it? Is it really supported?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you delete the user data folder of Chromium before starting Chromium? After you do that, Chromium will create a new user data folder again

Comment: I use other options that work fine. I don't have to include the `--` before the argument. I also provide a Chromium data folder (empty one):
`options.AddArgument($"user-data-dir={myPath}");`

Comment: I have also tested with `options.AddArgument("--disable-cookie-encryption");` and not working

Comment: Are you trying to run it in headless mode? After going through the Chromium's source I can see that it's designed for headless mode only. Also are you on *nix based OS? Looks like on Windows, it doesn't support cookie encryption

Comment: @Asesh I'm on Windows. Both Chrome, Chromium, and Edge (Chromium based browser) is encrypting the cookies. I'm not running the browsers in headless mode. I provide the `--disable-cookie-encryption` argument and the cookies are encrypted. Is it because it is only available in headless mode? Can you link me the relevant part of the source and some explanation please?

Comment: That switch is available in headless mode only. In headless mode, on Windows cookie encryption will be disabled regardless of that switch, but will be enabled on other OSs depending on whether that switch is present or not. Source: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:headless/lib/browser/headless_request_context_manager.cc;l=202;drc=23f61cb65a94208dc2c4728e895e87d47f64a8b6 Note this comment for disabling it on Windows: `On Windows, Cookie encryption requires access to local_state prefs, which are unavailable.`

Comment: You can try https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cookies_view.html for checking the cookies in unencrypted form. Its available from Version 1.60:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The webpage [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) still mentions the [`--disable-cookie-encryption`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-cookie-encryption) argument as follows:

```
--disable-cookie-encryption - Whether cookies stored as part of user profile are encrypted.
```

This setting is mentioned in [headless_shell_switches.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:headless/app/headless_shell_switches.cc;l=16?q=disable-cookie-encryption&sq=&ss=chromium) and possibly applicable only for `headless` mode.

```
// Copyright 2016 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

#include "headless/app/headless_shell_switches.h"

namespace headless {
namespace switches {

// The background color to be used if the page doesn't specify one. Provided as
// RGBA integer value in hex, e.g. 'ff0000ff' for red or '00000000' for
// transparent.
const char kDefaultBackgroundColor[] = "default-background-color";

// Whether cookies stored as part of user profile are encrypted.
const char kDisableCookieEncryption[] = "disable-cookie-encryption";
```

---

### Deep Dive

As per the article [Google Chrome to encrypt HTTP cookies on desktop systems](https://www.ghacks.net/2014/01/06/google-chrome-encrypt-http-cookies-desktop-systems-means/) [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) saves cookies to a file in the user's data folder. It is named `Cookies` and is a **SQLite** database. You can load it into any SQLeditor, for instance Firefox's SQLite Manager extension, to read all cookies that have been saved to the local system as a result of the user's Internet activities.

However, there is a [change](https://codereview.chromium.org/24734007) within Chromium as follows:

> Encrypt all stored cookies on selected operating systems.

> As part of the goal of protecting private user information, this encrypts the cookie values on operating systems with user-specific crypto APIs and that do not otherwise protect this data.

> Performance tests indicate a penalty of about 1ms per cookie  (regardless of size) on a Mac and 0.1ms to 0.7ms (depending on the size) under Windows.  This will be higher on older hardware but still insignificant.

> Encrypted data is binary (with an overhead of 128 bytes on Windows) and binary data must be stored in a BLOB so only one of two fields ("value" or "encrypted_value") will have data with the other being empty.  Both values, however, need to be read & written when accessing a cookie because they are marked "non null").

This change [enforces](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=313323) that all desktop versions of Google Chrome will encrypt stored cookies in the near future (while Chrome OS and Android use fully encrypted profiles already). This change only affects new cookies saved to the system after Chrome is updated with the new implementation. Existing cookies remain as is, while all new cookies will be encrypted by default by the browser.

---

### Trade-off

It is to be noted that the performance drop that goes along with encrypting cookies is insignificant. On [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) it is `1 ms` while on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) os it may slow down up to `0.7 ms`.

---

### Conclusion

It appears after enforcing the recent change in the cookie policy `disable-cookie-encryption` is no more effective.

Comment: I doubt your conclusion is correct because after going through the Chromium's source code, it should work on macOS and Linux. I have not tried it, so I am not 100% sure. But maybe you should try it and then come to a conclusion